# RadioButton with Listview.builder

Tags: flutter

I have radiobutton in my listview builder, listview builder building Cards, when calling the first radio button it changes from all subsequent Cards.
How can I isolate the radio button option for just the chosen card?

```
 Center(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: data != null ? data.length : 0,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                              Map data = snapshot.data[index];
                              //alts.length = 0;
                              if (data['alts'] != null) {
                                alts = json.decode(data['alts']);
                                alts.forEach((element) {});
                              } else
                                return snapshot.data[index]['alts'] =
                                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),
                                    child: Card(                                                                                    
                                                child: Container(
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            left: 0,
                                                            right: 25,
                                                            bottom: 15),
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      //  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                      //CrossAxisAlignment
                                                      //   .start,
                                                      mainAxisSize:
                                                          MainAxisSize.max,
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .spaceEvenly,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Row(children: [
                                                          Radio(
                                                              value: null,
                                                              groupValue:
                                                                  null,
                                                              onChanged:
                                                                  null),
                                                          Text(
                                                            'Certo',
                                                            style:
                                                                TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .black,
                                                              fontSize: 16,
                                                            ),
                                                          )
                                                        ]),
```

Comment: Why don't you provide some information about your data? Also, why are giving a null value to all properties of Radio widget? Please read the documentation carefully: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html

Comment: Radio is null because i haven't created yet anything to setstate...

Comment: "...when calling the first radio button it changes from all subsequent cards" -- That means the "value" property of every radio button is the same, in your case they are  all null. So Radio widget will compare null(value) == null(groupValue) which is true, hence the resulting behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try this small addition to your code:

```
Row(children: [
    Radio(
        key: UniqueKey(),  // add this line
        value: null,
        groupValue: null,
        onChanged: null
    ),
```

It provides a unique key for each radio button.